# Adding numbers to a table

Tags: jquery, loops

Im trying to add a number to each table row through javascript using `.length` by Looping through entire table and list the number for each row. I have been working really hard to get but I keep failing. Please help! Here's  my table:

```
<table class="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Last</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="person">
            <td class="number"></td>
            <td>Bill</td>
            <td>Sims</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="person">
            <td class="number"></td>
            <td>Jenny</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="person">
            <td class="number"></td>
            <td>Milo</td>
            <td>Resa</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`
```

So ideally it would look like this    1  Bill   Sims and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
   var index = $(this).index();
    $('.number', this).text(index +1);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cPLnX/)**

Comment: Or you can directly use `$('.number').each(function(i) {
     $(this).text(i +1);
});`  . If you want to use the `.length` property to get the things done it might be messy

Comment: Ok, for some reason I thought it would be easier to use .length

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('.mytable tr').each(function(i){
        $(this).find('td:first').text(i); // or $(this).find('td.number').text(i);
  //Use iterator's index argument 
    });
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    $('.mytable tr td.number').text(function(){
       return $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1; // get the parent tr's index() add 1 to get the #
    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/934gz/)

Answer (score 2):

I bet you got the answer from the other posts, but I'd prefer using **parent** when selecting the parent through the child (direct parent instead of travelling recursively) than using *closest* and **children** over *find* when selecting a direct child of the parent's (no traversal over descendants of children) because td is always the direct child of tr.

example:

```
$('table tr td.number').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).parent().index()+1); // you could use collection (like the next example) if you have one td with class 'number' per each tr
});
```

OR:

```
$('table tr').each(function(i){
    $(this).children('.number:first').text(i+1);
});
```

Regards,